# Old java textbook

Tags: java

I have a textbook,  "5th Edition Lewis and Loftus Java Software Solutions: Foundations of Program Design". The edition is from 2007. Can I use this to learn java, or is too outdated to be worth my time?

Comment: It should be fine. It'll cover Java 6 which is old but not *that* old. Note: this question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: Great, thanks. I learned python a few months prior to 3.x, and was in for some major relearning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is always changing but not be very much. I have used that book for the newest version of java and some stuff doesn't work but for the most part you should be good. If something doesn't work in that book then simple just go onto google or some other search engine and check out the new way.
Best of Luck,
Dev